# How to use grails-filter-0.2 plug in?

Tags: plugins, grails, filter

I want to use grails-filter-0.2 plugin in my app..I am not getting any tutorial on how to use it.

i got this **http://www.grails.org/Filter+plugin** but this link contains a demo example but i want a detailed tutorial on how to use it.can any one send me if any link as such.

with advance thanks
laxmi

Answer (score 2):

You're very unlikely to find a more detailed source of information about the plugin than the official docs. If there's something you're not clear about, post a question about the issue itself, rather than a question asking for a URL that solves your (undefined) problem.

Comment: can i use collection instead of bean in filter tag.

Comment: I am not using DB in my app..i have collection for which i want to apply filters..is that possible with filter plug in

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what happened?